Proof that $\int_{C} f(z)dz =\int_{C_1} f(z)dz +\int_{C_2} f(z)dz + \cdots \int_{C_n} f(z)dz$
Let $C=C_1 \cup C_2 \cup \cdots \cup C_n$, where the individual pieces $C_i$ are of class $C^1$, i want to prove that
$$\int_{C} f(z)dz =\int_{C_1} f(z)dz +\int_{C_2} f(z)dz + \cdots \int_{C_n} f(z)dz$$
Let $z(t)$ A parameterization of the curve $C$ for $a \leq t \leq a$.
I suppose the idea is to decompose in a numerable quantity, the parameterization in a reparametrization of the different sections that compose it (when they are traversed in different times), I consider that expressing something like
\begin{align*}
\int_{C} f(z) dz &= \int_{a}^{b_1} f(z_1(t))z_1'(t) dt + \int_{a_2}^{b_2} f(z_2(t))z_2'(t) dt + \cdots + \int_{a_n}^{b} f(z_n(t))z_n'(t) dt \\
&=\int_{C_1} f(z)dz +\int_{C_2} f(z)dz + \cdots \int_{C_n} f(z)dz
\end{align*}
Of course I am not giving a proof, I am just giving an idea of what the proof can be, but, how to write this in a better way? any suggestion? or any alternative way? I will be grateful!

What is your definition of $C_1 \cup C_2 \cup \cdots \cup C_n$ ?

@MartinR In fact, I was not given clarity on that, I guess it is the usual one, but to my interpretation it is a union of smooth curves, I guess I can give you another one in order to prove what I asked for.
Note: the curves are joined at each end.

This seems more like a matter of definition than proof.

I am pretty sure that the pieces have to be disjoint. Otherwise you claim that $\int_Cf(z),dz=\int_Cf(z),dz+\int_Cf(z),dz,.$

I guess the only ambiguity is that the parameterization on each piece of the curve must be chosen such that the piecewise parameterization is still monotone
